# MySQL - Counting rows and left join problem

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I have 2 tables, campaigns and campaign_codes:

campaigns: id, partner_id, status

campaign_codes: id, code, status

I want to get a count of all campaign_codes for all campaigns WHERE campaign_codes.status equals 0 OR where there are no campaign_codes records for a campaign.

I have the following SQL, but of course the WHERE statement eliminates those campaigns which have no corresponding records in campaign_codes ( i want those campaigns with zero campaign_codes as well)

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS campaign_id, 
    COUNT(cc.id) AS code_count
FROM 
    campaigns c
LEFT JOIN campaign_codes cc on cc.campaign_id = c.id
WHERE c.partner_id = 4
AND cc.status = 0
GROUP BY c.id
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd opt for something like:

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS campaign_id, 
    COUNT(cc.id) AS code_count
FROM 
    campaigns c
LEFT JOIN campaign_codes cc on cc.campaign_id = c.id
AND cc.status = 0 -- Having this clause in the WHERE, effectively makes this an INNER JOIN
WHERE c.partner_id = 4
GROUP BY c.id
```

Moving the `AND` to the join clause makes the join succeed or fail, crucially keeping resulting rows in where there is no matching row in the 'right' table.

If it were in the `WHERE`, the comparisons to NULL (where there is no campaign_code) would fail, and be eliminated from the results.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Would love an explanation or pointer to some reading on how the AND is being used.

Comment: What I am asking is if someone can explain or point me to a resource on placing the AND before the WHERE. Haven't used that in the past and not sure I really understand it.

Comment: @k00k added a bit more detail as to "why"

Comment: appreciate it, ta very much! :)

Comment: It doesn't need to be an additional where clause, either. You can simply do an inner join and add the "add" condition to the join. Same effect, slightly cleaner imho :)

Comment: but if you want to have left join? I came to this question because exaclty I have left join problem. The joined cells have nulls if they are not existing but still counted as 1

Comment: @Darius.V this question wanted to include records where there were no records in the joined table as a thing - sounds like you have a similar, but different, question, so would suggest asking a new question :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS campaign_id, 
    COUNT(cc.id) AS code_count
FROM 
    campaigns c
LEFT JOIN campaign_codes cc on cc.campaign_id = c.id
    AND c.partner_id = 4
    AND cc.status = 0
GROUP BY c.id
```